# Activerecord, error on scope with association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to clean out some bots from my user database.

I have these models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_one :user_profile,           dependent: :destroy
  scope :possible_bots, -> { joins(:user_profile).where("id > ?", 20000).where.not(user_profile: {description: ''}).where.not(user_profile: {website: ''}) }
end
```

Basically every user with id > 20000 that has compiled the "description" or the "website" field inside the user_profile is a bot.

I have this error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous)
LINE 1: ...N "user_profiles"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE (id > 20000...
```

Comment: *Basically every user with id > 20000 that has compiled the "description" or the "website" field inside the user_profile is a bot* -- looks strange. May be it's better to have boolean column `bot` for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

With `joins(:user_profile)` you introduced second id column to the query (`user_profiles.id`) and you have to specify the `users.id` column explicitly.

```rb
scope :possible_bots, -> { joins(:user_profile).where("users.id > ?", 20000).where.not(user_profiles: {description: ''}).where.not(user_profiles: {website: ''}) }
```

Furthermore you say description OR website field, while the query you provided does AND. Scope for OR would be something like this:

```rb
scope :possible_bots, -> { joins(:user_profile).where("users.id > ?", 20000).where.not(user_profiles: {description: ''}).or(User.joins(:user_profile).where("users.id > ?", 20000).where.not(user_profiles: {website: ''})) }
```

Comment: ArgumentError (Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:joins])

Comment: @RobertoPezzali Updated the asnwer, forgot about the `joins`.

Comment: Still have some errors.

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "user_profile")
LINE 1: ..._id" = "users"."id" WHERE ((users.id > 20000) AND "user_prof...

I will try to debug them looking at the sql

Comment: @RobertoPezzali I added the ID column to the `or` because I think it should be there. The undefined table happened because the where condition for the join table should use the table name not association name.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use `or()` here because you're just setting yourself up for introducing errors and it's not DRY. Using raw SQL will be much cleaner: `where("user_profiles.description != '' OR user_profiles.website != ''")`.

Comment: @jeffdill2 I agree but I'm not a regular PostreSQL user and I have nowhere to try a query right now so I am not comfortable writing custom queries in this case.

Comment: @jeffdill2 Raw SQL introduces its own set of issues instead we can leverage the underlying AST (`Arel`). `UserProfile.arel_table[:description].not_eq('').or(UserProfile.arel_table[:website].not_eq(''))`. This makes the code portable between databases and allows for the UserProfile table name to change in the future without breaking the code.

Comment: @engineersmnky that introduces the same issues with non-DRY code though, since you'd have to have all of your other queries that are part of the scope – such as `where("users.id > ?", 20000)` – duplicated at least once, depending on how many `OR`s you need. Personally, I don't make future-proofing considerations for database portability. I'm sure that's something that some folks have had to deal with. But in 16 years of coding, it's just not something I've ever had to deal with. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @jeffdill2 there is nothing different about what I provided when compared to what you provided. e.g. the full query would be `User.joins(:user_profile).where("users.id > ?", 20000).where(UserProfile.arel_table[:description].not_eq('').or(UserProfile.arel_table[:website].not_eq('')))`. I find raw SQL error prone and abhorrent in rails but that's just a personal preference.

Comment: @engineersmnky ahhh right right, I guess you wouldn't need to include the `where("users.id > ?", 20_000)` in the call to `UserProfile` that you're passing to the `or()`. So yeah, your solution would be DRY. :thumbsup: